# Use of Twitter, Facebook, Google profile and LinkedIn fields in profile edit?

Tags: support, profile-page, social-networking

I've just noticed some new fields when editing my profile. Filling them in doesn't seem to display anything so do they have any use or is this a feature in progress?

Comment: Uh-oh. I hope this doesn't ruin my favorite Meta answer of all time: "Stack Overflow is *not* a social networking site!"

Comment: @Cody Actually I think this would help with that. With links available in profiles, they should stop asking for social features here, right?

Comment: Update for anyone wondering... sometime after this question was posted, these fields have vanished from the profile edit form.

Comment: Now you tell me. I moved all my contact info to those fields ^^

Comment: @Cody: Don't worry, if the whole of the web goes social the internet will go sentient and we will absorbed into an electronic overmind.

Comment: @James: From what I've seen of "social networking", that's not a real big concern. There's nothing remotely "sentient" about it.

Comment: I'll have to agree with you on that :D

Answer (score 4):

***poke*** I was just reminded [by this related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116325/add-authors-twitter-user-name-to-the-posts-tweeted-by-stack-exchanges-twitter) that these fields had existed. I think they were removed not long after being added. Has the idea been discarded, or is it still [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)?