# Add author's Twitter user name to the posts tweeted by Stack Exchanges' Twitter accounts

Tags: feature-request, community, twitter

It would be nice if the posts tweeted by the various Twitter accounts Stack Exchange's sites have would @-reference the author of the post. Give us some love.

[image: Screenshot of tweets]

To know the twitter @username, our SE profile should have an extra field for that, but that is a feature that has already [been mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29547/add-a-twitter-field-to-user-profiles).

Comment: But how would it *know* the name of our Twitter accounts? (If we have one, to start with.)

Comment: (Like: http://twitter.com/#!/arjan is not me!)

Comment: I think it has already been discussed in meta, giving the option of adding the twitter account on your profile. As simple as that. All the rest is bot magic.

Comment: So the message would @-reference all the users with an account on the site containing the question, wouldn't it?

Comment: @kiamlaluno it should @-reference the user who posted the question/answer that is being tweeted.

Comment: @Naoise, note the "edit" link then!

Comment: @Arjan I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: It seems @kiamlaluno and I did not understand what *exactly* you're asking for, or were trying to trigger you into being more specific. Rather than answering using comments, please enhance the question for future readers! (Use the "edit" link to do so.) Thanks!

Comment: I actually thought that this feature request was about tweeted questions that should @-reference all the users who answered that question.

Comment: I really think it is unambiguous, can't see how to reformat the question but will try.

Comment: Twitter integration on SE, more generally speaking, would be pretty sweet though.

Comment: note how some tweets say "great answer", instead of posting the question. So some times it is the author of the **answer** (not the post) who deserves the love